# Getting the Unique Transaction ID seen by the customer from Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm using PayPal Express Checkout on a sandbox account, and i'm trying to link up the Unique Transaction ID on the "customer" paypal site with the completed transaction via Express Checkout.

My `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` returned:

```
TOKEN=EC%2d2KG36160AM8868619&
SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED=false&
TIMESTAMP=2015%2d01%2d29T09%3a45%3a09Z&
CORRELATIONID=44060412ed341&
ACK=Success&
VERSION=93&BUILD=15009693&
INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED=false&
SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT=false&
PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID=011446947E558235S&
PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE=expresscheckout&
PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE=instant&
PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME=2015%2d01%2d29T09%3a45%3a08Z&
PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT=7%2e98&
PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT=0%2e47&
PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT=0%2e00&
PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE=GBP&
PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS=Completed&
PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON=None&
PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE=None&
PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY=Ineligible&
PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE=None&
PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID=W9SM36U76AXSS&
PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE=0&
PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK=Success
```

Then my GetExpressCheckoutDetails returned:

```
TOKEN=EC%2d2KG36160AM8868619&
BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS=0&
CHECKOUTSTATUS=PaymentActionCompleted&
TIMESTAMP=2015%2d01%2d29T09%3a45%3a33Z&
CORRELATIONID=80e00a0067bea&
ACK=Success&
VERSION=93&
BUILD=15009693&
EMAIL=test1%40sud%2eco2euk&
PAYERID=H54VEN293PLFL&
PAYERSTATUS=verified&
FIRSTNAME=Test&
LASTNAME=User&
COUNTRYCODE=GB&
CURRENCYCODE=GBP&
AMT=7%2e98&
SHIPPINGAMT=0%2e00&
HANDLINGAMT=0%2e00&
TAXAMT=0%2e00&
INSURANCEAMT=0%2e00&
SHIPDISCAMT=0%2e00&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=GBP&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=7%2e98&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=0%2e00&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT=0%2e00&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0%2e00&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT=0%2e00&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=0%2e00&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TRANSACTIONID=011446947E558235S&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED=false&
PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID=011446947E558235S&
PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE=0
```

But the customer site says:

PayPal Express Checkout Payment Sent (Unique Transaction ID 7PK53077PJ222701T)

Comment: Yeah... this is a PayPal oddity: each party in the transaction gets their own transaction ID. I'm not aware of any way for one party to get another party's transaction ID. Fortunately, most if not all of PayPal's search functions will accept either ID. For example if a customer gives you *their* ID for a transaction that you are a party to, you can search that ID up in your PP account or the TransactionDetails API. But if you want to have something shared that you and a customer can discuss to identify a transaction you may need to add an invoice ID as you perform the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh..the (painful) memories :) That aforementioned "oddity" also exists elsewhere - e.g. eBay transactions

IINM, you'll need to send your own "custom ID" - the `Invoice Id` mentioned above (which is displayed to the end user) so both ends have some *visual* reference to a transaction.

In the REST API (unsure in Classic, haven't tried), if you send an `Order`, the Order Number (finally) is shared on both ends (same for both). Though it wouldn't hurt to still send your own "custom Id"/"Invoice Id".

**Buyer/Customer Paypal UI**:
[image: Buyer Visual ref]

**Seller/Merchant Paypal UI**:
[image: Seller Visual ref]
Hth...

Comment: Confirmed, setting the INVOICE property when calling the SetExpressCheckout method stores the invoice value with paypal, the invoice value is then returned when you receive the IPN